# Why jQuery validation funcs are not working in ASP.NET MVC Core app?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-core-mvc

I have ASP.NET Core MVC app and I want to use jQuery client-side validation.
I import scripts in _Layout.cshtml and I see them in Source files:

```
 <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"></script>
 <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/additional-methods.js"></script>
 <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Unobtrusive validation working good when I'm using simple submit button with MVC form (asp-action & asp-controller). Errors appears and it's OK. But the problem occurs when I'm using Ajax for submit form to controller and I want call jQuery validation functions like 
*.validate(),  $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form')* etc.

Then there are errors in Console like:

> $(...).validate is not a function 
>   $.validator is undefined

I tried to put scripts in views, directly before the script in which I use them. I put my script in _Layout.cshtml too, but it didn't help.

Comment: Try to refer to the replies to related threads provided in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56266577/asp-net-core-validate-is-not-a-function-manual-validate-trigger) which may be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").each(function () { $.data($(this)[0], 'validator', false); });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
});
```

Comment: it still return _$.validator is undefined_ . I found that we can load scripts via PartialView. In ASP.NET Core MVC app there is default validation Parial `_ValidationScriptPartial` but it's not helped.
`@section Scripts {
    @await Html.PartialAsync("~/Views/Shared/_ValidationScriptsPartial.cshtml")
    <script src="~/js/myScriptWhereIWantToUseValidator.js"></script>
}`

Comment: [link](https://www.paste.org/103706) _Layout.cshtml
[link](https://www.paste.org/103707) View.cshtml
[link](https://www.paste.org/103708) _FormPartialView.cshtml

And in tyresItems.js  I want to use validation methods, i.e. `$('#addTyreItem-form').validate()` but it's not working.

Comment: maybe it's happen because opening modal with form rendering them on the bottom of DOM, after all <script> tags too.